# Failed to execute spring boot application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm new to spring, and getting below error message whenever I tried to run my spring boot main script.

```
  ***************************
  APPLICATION FAILED TO START
  ***************************

  Description:

  Field testrepo in com.online.XXX.app.dao.TestDAO required a bean 
  named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.


   Action:
  Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.
```

Below is my DAO class:

```
@Service
public class TestDAO 
{

    @Autowired
    private TestRep testrepo;


    public List<E2ETestsDTO> finaAll() {
        return testrepo.findAll();
    }

 }
```

I have pojo class like below:

```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "testXXX")
  @EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
  public class E2ETestsDTO 
 {
    @NotBlank
    private String test_id;

    @NotBlank
    private String test_name;

    public String getTest_id() 
   {
        return test_id;
   }

    public void setTest_id(String test_id) 
   {
        this.test_id = test_id;
   }

    public String getTest_name() 
    {
        return test_name;
    }

    public void setTest_name(String test_name) 
    {
        this.test_name = test_name;
    }

 }
```

The below is jpa repository:

```
 @Repository
 public interface TestRep extends JpaRepository<E2ETestsDTO, Long> 
 {

 }
```

The below is the controller class file:

```
    @RestController
    @RequestMapping("/amzonrunner")
    public class TestController 
   {

        @Autowired
        TestDAO testdao;

        @GetMapping("/sample")
        public List<E2ETestsDTO> getAllTestRecords()
        {
            return testdao.finaAll();
        }
   }
```

The below one is main code:

```
 @SpringBootApplication
 @EnableJpaAuditing
 //@EnableJpaRepositories("com.online.xxx.app")
 public class TestApplication 
 {

    public static void main(String args[])throws Exception
    {
        SpringApplication.run(TestApplication.class);
    }

  }
```

Any leads help me to resolve this issue? why its failed to start.

Comment: It is screaming at the top of it's lungs: `Field productrepo in com.online.paypal.app.dao.ProductDAO required a bean 
  named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.`

Comment: Which generally means that you don't have a JPA starter enabled.

Comment: I have below dependency in pom.xml  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been given wrong value in application.properties.

```
Before:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect;

After:

spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Also removed @Entity annotation.

Now it working fine.